# Google Directory API - How to get the resulting deserialized objects of a BatchRequest

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-directory-api

i am trying to speed up some google directory api calls in the .net client library with BatchRequests

lets say i have the following batchRequest (which consists only of one
request for simplicity):

```
    static async Task BatchRequesting()
    {
        var batchReq = new BatchRequest(_dirservices[0]);

        var r = _dirservices[0].Users.Get("user@domain.com");
        batchReq.Queue<UsersResource.GetRequest>(r,
            (contentReq, error, j, message) =>
        {
              ... what to do here?
        });

        await batchReq.ExecuteAsync();
    }
```

how do i get the resulting deserialized response object in the callback (which would be a User object in my case)
Do i have to handle the message.Content object (HttpContent) myself with all the json deserializing?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I used the wrong generic parameter. My Code example has to be like this:

```
static async Task BatchRequesting()
{
    var batchReq = new BatchRequest(_directoryService);

    var request = _directoryService.Users.Get("user@domain.com");
    batchReq.Queue<User>(request,
        (returnedUser, error, j, message) =>
    {
           if (error != null)
           {
              Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
           }
            else
           {
             ... work with returnedUser
           }
    });

    await batchReq.ExecuteAsync();
}
```